# Что за параметр 'rb' у функции open?

Tags: python

Что за параметр 'rb' у функции open?

```
def welcome(message):
    sti = open('static/welcome.webp', 'rb')
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start']) #реагирует на команду старт
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)
```

Comment: В любом учебнике Python рассказывается https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/fajly-rabota-s-fajlami.html

Answer (score 4):

Режим открытия файла - read binary.

Comment: По моему скромному мнению, стоит добавить, что это не имеет никакого отношения к pyTelegramBotAPI, как автор вопроса думал до этого.

Comment: @mrEvgenX, потому я у вопроса и сделал только метку [tag:python], а не метку библиотеки или телеграма.

Answer (score 0):

для двоичной записи объекта, будь то картинка или видео